# ASP.NET code cannot get OAuth2 token, but PostMan can

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, postman

I have some code that I am trying to (in my opinion) simplify to get the OAuth token for a Web API request.

I tested the process in PostMan originally setting the auth token request as part of the "authorization" tab of the main request. This works great. If I set the auth token request as its own separate entity in PostMan also works great.

In C# however, it never responds. I have other code where this same request works just fine (different service, etc, but same code layout).

C# code:

```
public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(AuthTokenUrl);
            var request = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
                ["client_id"] = AuthClientId,
                ["client_secret"] = AuthClientSecret,
                ["scope"] = AuthScope
            });

            var resp = await client.PostAsync("", request);

            if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<AccessTokenModel>();
                return content.access_token;
            }

            Log.Error("API Token Request unsuccessful. Status code: {code}; Reason: {reason}, {@request}", resp.StatusCode, resp.ReasonPhrase, request);

            return null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex, "Error while retrieving auth token for API.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Postman:

[image: PostMan Request]

Working C# example:

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetOktaToken()
{
    using (var oktaClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        oktaClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AuthUrl);
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "scope.read")
                , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ClientId)
                , new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", ClientSecret)
            });

        var resp = await oktaClient.PostAsync(string.Empty, content);

        var oktaresp = await resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<OktaResponse>();

        return oktaresp.access_token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, clarify your question. You wrote that in C# "it never responds", but what do you mean by that ? Does your HTTP request timeout ? Do you get an error status code ? What else ?

Comment: Another question, are you sure about the URL you are providing inside the PostAsync method ? You are actually passing an empty string there. Based on my knowledge, the request path for a token endpoint is never an empty request path. Try to double check that.

Comment: I mean it just never comes back at all, the site sits there with the browser showing the "waiting for response" icon, no exception or anything.  I am actually about to close this question though because I figured it out.  I was trying to call the sort of "daisy-chain" of async requests from a non-async method using the .Result property. I recall from another time that this can be problematic in some scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you had is an interesting one. It has nothing to do with the OAuth2 token negotiation, instead it was a deadlock in your action method: this is why you noticed that your HTTP request never completed and got stuck with no apparent explanation.

The root cause of this problem is that in classic ASP.NET (that is .NET framework ASP.NET implementation) there is a thing called **ASP.NET request context**. The main rule for the ASP.NET request context is that **it only allows one thread in at the time**. This basically means that if there is a thread executing inside a given ASP.NET request context, no other thread can be executed in that same request context.

Remember also how an asynchronous method works when it encounters the `await` keyword: it captures the **context** in which it is executed and, by default, it tries to resume its execution inside the captured context.
The exact meaning of the word *context* entirely depends on the type of application: if you have a classic ASP.NET application this context is the ASP.NET request context mentioned above.

Consider now this example. You have a classic ASP.NET application, where you have the following action method. Notice that this action method is synchronous and that it blocks its execution when the asynchronous method `GetMessageAsync` is invoked:

```
public sealed class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMessage()
    {
        var message = GetMessageAsync().Result;
        return new TextResult(message, Request);
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of the `GetMessageAsync` asynchronous method:

```
public async Task<string> GetMessageAsync()
{
  await Task.Delay(5000);
  return "Hello World!";
}
```

If you create a simple web api application which tries to execute this code, you will get a deadlock in your application.
Here is why:

1. when a client sends a GET request against your application, one thread is taken from the ASP.NET thread pool to serve that request. Let's call this thread THREAD 1. THREAD 1 enters the ASP.NET request context for the incoming HTTP request and starts executing the `GetMessage` action method.
2. THREAD 1 starts executing the `GetMessageAsync` method. Execution continues until the `Task.Delay` method is invoked. This method returns an uncompleted `Task` which will eventually complete after 5 seconds: this `Task` indicates that the execution of `Task.Delay` is not completed and will eventually complete in the future. Since `GetMessageAsync` is an asynchronous method and the `await` keyword is used in front of `Task.Delay`, the execution of `GetMessageAsync` is interrupted and the method returns an uncompleted `Task`. This `Task` indicates that the execution of `GetMessageAsync` is not completed and will eventually complete in the future. Notice also that the `await` keyword has automatically captured the execution context (which is, in this case, the ASP.NET request context) so that, once the `Task` returned by `Task.Delay` will be completed, the execution of `GetMessageAsync` will resume on the captured context.
3. Since the `Task` returned by `GetMessageAsync` is uncompleted, the execution of the `GetMessage` method cannot continue beyond the first line. The method stops at the line where `GetMessageAsync` method is invoked and THREAD 1 stays there blocked, synchronously waiting for the completion of the `Task` returned by `GetMessageAsync`. This happens because the get accessor of `Task<T>.Result` property [is blocking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8.1#remarks).
4. Eventually, the `Task` returned by `Task.Delay` completes. At this point, the runtime needs to resume the execution of the `GetMessageAsync` method inside the context captured by the `await` keyword. Remember that this context is the ASP.NET request context for the incoming HTTP request. A thread is then taken from the ASP.NET thread pool, let's call this thread THREAD 2. This thread should, at this point, enter the ASP.NET request context and continue the execution of the `GetMessageAsync` method past the `await` keyword. Unfortunately this is not allowed, because there is already a thread executing inside the ASP.NET request context: it is the THREAD 1 thread, which is stuck waiting for the completion of the `Task` returned by the `GetMessageAsync` method.
5. At this point you have a deadlock: THREAD 1 is waiting for the completion of the `Task` returned by the `GetMessageAsync` method and THREAD 2 is waiting for the ASP.NET request context to be available in order to execute the remaining part of the `GetMessageAsync` method. ASP.NET request context is not available, since THREAD 1 is currently executing inside that context.

The solution to avoid this kind of situations is to **never ever blocks on asynchronous code**. If you are writing modern C# code in a platform where the `async` and `await` keywords are available, always use asynchronous methods and use the `await` keyword when you invoke asynchronous code. APIs like [`Task.Wait()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.8.1#system-threading-tasks-task-wait) and [`Task<T>.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8.1) are blocking and should never be used if you are inside an asynchronous context.

Refer to [this article](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) if you want further information on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was the way I was trying to call the async method chain in the first place.  I was using a non-async controller action to execute the requests by way of the `.Result` property.

Bad code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {                
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        /// for local testing api
        var brands = Helpers.API.APIHelper.GetListAsync("requestedvalue").Result;
        /// Other tasks

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Better Code:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {                
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        /// for local testing
        var items = await Helpers.API.APIHelper.GetListAsync("requestedvalue");
        /// Other tasks

        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Once I made my action async and used await I got results from the async requests. Disappointing that I didn't figure that out sooner and I do not recall the reason why this matters today, but I had a similar issue in my second example in my question (the "working" one) and had to make the same sort of change in the other project.

Comment: Is this cose executed in classic ASP.NET or in ASP.NET core?

Comment: By classic ASP.NET I mean full framework (.NET Framework)

Comment: .NET Framework 4.6.2